# Is there a way to enable conditional formatting in the Excel for Windows Phone?

Tags: onedrive, office

I was just demonstrating to a fellow Windows Phone user that the phone has Excel (a fact that had escaped attention.) Combined with OneDrive syncing, this seemed like a perfect solution to a problem this family member was facing, so there was a lot of excitement... until the synced document was opened on the phone and none of the conditional formatting worked.

I poked around under the menus a bit and can't find anything useful. Is this just a totally diluted version of Excel, or can we actually make the spreadsheet useful on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Environment: Nokia Lumia 521 running WP8.1 DP with latest updates.

Confirmed:  Excel on the phone is watered down.  I've got a spreadsheet saved into OneDrive that has Conditional formatting and list inputs, and neither work on the phone.  I'm happy to be able to have Excel on my phone, but I'm glad I don't need to rely on that spreadsheet day-to-day.